# How to set log4net LockingModel programmatically after loading with XmlConfigurator?

Tags: c#, log4net, xmlconfigurator

I have this XML log4net configuration:

```
  <log4net>
    <appender name="myAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="mylog.txt" />
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="DEBUG" />
        <appender-ref ref="myAppender" />
    </root>
  </log4net>
```

I load this configuration with the C# line below, and it works well:

```
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(path);
```

**PROBLEM:** Now I want to set the `lockingModel` to `MinimalLock`. **Programmatically**, not in XML.
How to do it?

That would be the equivalent of adding `<lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />` in the XML configuration.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
// assumes there are not multiple file appenders defined
var appender = log4net.LogManager.GetRepository()
                                 .GetAppenders()
                                 .OfType<FileAppender>()
                                 .SingleOrDefault();

if (appender != null)
{
     appender.LockingModel = new FileAppender.MinimalLock();
}
```

Comment: So I guess I should insert this code just after my `log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(path);` line?

Comment: Yes, it needs to run after the configuration has been loaded.

Answer (score -2):

```
    <appender name="text" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender,log4net">
        <param name="File" value="c:\system-name.log"/>
        <param name="AppendToFile" value="true"/>
        <rollingStyle value="Date"/>
        <staticLogFileName value="true"/>
        <datePattern value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd"/>
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n"/>
        </layout>
enter code here
        <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock"/>
    </appender>
```

Comment: The OP has asked how to do this programmatically, rather than via config